# Architecture for mobile application

Tags: mobile, web-applications, architecture

Right now ,i and my friend looking forward to make a mobile application, which is going to get data from several different sources, analyze it with some kind of algorythm and make the best decision on that. The main problem is - right architecture for that. We consider that mobile application is going to be just a client, representing data placed somewhere on internet (anyway internet is required).

Can u help us with making right choice?
We have some kind of knowledge about client-server architecture with sockets... But this is definetly not we need in this particular situation.

Our thought is to make a web site which is going to generate all the required data.After that implement mobile apps which will represent info from website, using convenient interface. Is it right way?

Comment: Best way how someone can help - make a small note about all possible architectures with adv and disadvantages) Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to go.

Now, you have several options within that architecture...

- server gets data from several different sources
- server might expose some kind of RESTful API to the client apps
- clients can be native mobile applications or client might be html5 mobile apps
- depending on the nature of the data, you might want to consider some kinds of caching data that you get from 3rd party services/sources

EDIT:

I use ASP WebApi to build REST Api that serves json data to android mobile app.
So, my infrastructure is:
- MS SQL 2012
- ASP MVC 4, WebAPI
- android mobiles (we're targeting mainly Jelly Bean & Kit Kat)

I've built n-layered application with layers (bottom up order):
- DAL (i don't use any ORM framework...i use my own repository that runs stored procedures on SQL server)

- Repository that wraps around db DAL and a few Service Agents that gets data from 3rd party services we use
- Business layer where i do our business operations
- Service layer (for now, it has no special use but afterwards i might need it as my business layer will be consumed from a few clients: WebAPI, web site, windows service...)
- WebAPI for REST where mobile client requests end up

Comment: Sounds good, but can u name any programming methods to start with?

Comment: At the moment, i'm working on one such application but honestly, i'm not sure i understand what exactly do you mean by 'programming method'? Could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: Sry, i mean something like asp.net or php site, or maybe it should be just a web service... not really sure that i named correct ways of realisation... Or just describe the way u going to do it,ofc if u can:)

Comment: You're welcome, sir! If there are some specific questions you feel i could help with, feel free to ask. I'll share what i know.